# Why is Infinity-Infinity NaN?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with this peculiar scenario mentioned below. Could someone please explain to me what's the reason for the following behavior.

Why is `Infinity - Infinity` results `NaN, but NaN === (Infinity-Infinity)` results `false` ?

Comment: because `NaN !== NaN`.

Comment: Infinity is sometimes defined as the ability to define a subset that doesn't include all elements but is also infinite. Substracting infinity from infinity doesn't give a set outcome and is therefor not a number. That said it's impossible to validate wether 2 things are equal if all you know is that both are not numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The answer lies in the **full form of NaN**.
NaN stands for **Not a Number**.
Hence, if something is not a number, it cannot be compared or checked for equality.

Going mathematically,

```
Infinity - Infinity = NaN   (1)

NaN == Infinity - Infinity  (2)
```

Here in (1) NaN holds a value that signifies the result is not quantifiable.

And in (2) you are checking the equality of 2 entities that are not quantifiable.

Hope that makes sense.

P.S. I know string values can be compared, but that is not the case with NaN.