# Why is 1/0=Infinity and 1/-0=-Infinity

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

Why is this so:

```
1 === 1;// true
0 === -0;// true
1/0 === 1/-0;// false
```

Reason:

```
1/0=Infinite;
1/-0=-Infinite;
```

Question:

*Why isn't 1/0 or 1/-0 **Undefined** or **NaN**?*

> It can't be Infinity or -Infinity, because of 0 is equal to -0, so 1/0 is equal to 1/-0 I should say, but why it isn't? And why it isn't Undefined (what my calculator says) or NaN.

Comment: Because IEEE-754 says so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Infinity-Infinity NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807110/why-is-infinity-infinity-nan)

Comment: Because the spec says so. Don't read any *mathematical* meaning into it, it's just the convention that was decided was more useful (to *programmers*) than alternatives

Comment: NaN = Not a number but in that operation you are working with numbers so it wouldn't make sense to divide two numbers and get a "Not a number" result.

Comment: Related: [Differentiating +0 and -0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7223717/4642212) and [Are +0 and -0 the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7223359/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the [IEEE 754 specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682005/why-does-division-by-zero-in-ieee754-standard-results-in-infinite-value) define it like that.

There is however a reasoning for this: the [affinely extended real number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)  extends the real numbers with the two infinities, which gives some more room for calculating with [limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function). So with this extension a division by zero is not `undefined` or `NaN`.

Consider that the following is true for positive *x*:

lim<sub>x→0</sub>(x) = lim<sub>x→0</sub>(-x)

However the following is ***not true*** for positive *x*:

lim<sub>x→0</sub>(1/x) = lim<sub>x→0</sub>(1/-x)

Note how the above comparisons with limit notation map to the comparisons you listed:

```
0 === -0;// true
1/0 === 1/-0;// false
```

Secondly, a division always maintains the following invariance: the result is negative if and only when exactly one of the operands is negative.

Both of these considerations give some credence as to why in IEEE 754:

```
1/0 === Infinity
1/-0 === -Infinity
```